# Why is init not a class method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation

Why is the `init` method not a class method?  I mean `init`'s method body starts with an `-`.
Methods starting with `-` are instance methods as far as I know, but obviously we want to create an instance.

Comment: `init` is not a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - it's the [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29) for an instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`init` is not for *creating* an instance; that's `alloc`'s job (and `alloc` *is* a class method).

`init` is for *setting up* the created instance. It needs access to the new instance's ivars, and *must* be an instance method.

Comment: Another installment of [bikeshedding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bike-shed-problem-and-so). I wish upvotes were actually proportional to effort.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @methanol; I forgot you would be notified of that comment. I was addressing anyone else who came by and felt compelled to vote. No, I meant that I should have gotten _fewer_. This answer took me less than a minute to type out, and I don't feel like it's worth seven upvotes.

Comment: the upvotes are not directly proportional to the quality  of answer, but quality of person who posted it. So here your comes into play. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: That's exactly how it's _not_ supposed to be. More reputation shouldn't lead directly to more reputation. Votes are about the content, not the person.

Comment: In meta I read about excess voting to celebrities, even on wrong answers they(John Skeet) got +5 votes :D

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Yes, that's also a problem; not really anything that can be done about it, though.

Comment: A click isnt that much effort. In fact its a nice touch nothing more. Dont take it too serious. Your life probably wont be better with more online reputation ;-)